# Internet issue in Ubuntu 16.04 and split terminal horizontally

Tags: 16.04

I need to split the screen horizontally into two. I found some commands like `CTRL+B` but it does not work. In addition sometime internet does not work in Ubuntu 16.04 installed in virtual machine. In virtual box settings I have selected NAT. I also have reboot the machine but no internet in Mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

Konsole has a view , split view, horizontally but that gives a separate tab new window at the bottom and not a split of one screen.